# Unable to Build Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin.forms

I set up a new environment on a new desktop computer. I cloned the project from the git repo and finally got it to build. For some reason the errors appear to be random but one error keeps showing consistently.

> Metadata file 'C:\\bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\MyProject.dll'
>   could not be found

I can create a new project and that base project runs fine. The cloned project used to run on the PCL and was converted to netstandard a while back prior to 2.0 release.

Comment: try to delete bin folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your project is targeting `netstandard 1.4`. Right click you project and choose `properties`. In `Application` option Set `Target Framework` to `netstandard 2`.
 Enjoy huge set of `API` and new crossplatform framework that is `netstandard 2`. If unable to target netstandard 2 install `dotnetcore` from the visual studio installer.

Comment: I am getting other errors now for some reason but you hit the nail on the head for the issue I posted on. I was missing dotnetcore. I installed it and that issue went away.